# Why couldn't people escape from the Rumbling by hiding in basements?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The Rumbling is supposed to eliminate all life outside the walls, and we know people can't escape by climbing mountains because the Titans will walk over them. But how about basements?

Shouldn't some people be able to escape by hiding in basements? The footprints shown of the Titans don't seem to be so deep as to make someone unable to escape by hiding in a deep basement. Or are people also killed by other means when the Rumbling happens, such as high surrounding temperature or something?

Comment: Well, I think it isn't clear how much the colossal titans weight, or how much pressure they exercise with their feet, but leaving a 40cm-deep footprint on concrete is not that easy. Tanks, which are around 50t in weight, don't do it, but they weight enough to fall into basements through the floor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to their extreme weight literally flattening everything, the titan release a lot of hot steam that burns and causes fires with the sheer heat released.

So even if the basement somehow survived the weight, the titan's heat would bake the inhabitants alive.